# Homomorphism from infinite to fixed graph

Tags: graph-theory

How to prove that if there is a homomorphism between two graphs, from one infinite $G^*$ to one finite and fixed $G'$, there is also a homomorphism from every subgraph $G^{**}$ of $G^*$ to $G'$? Should I first prove that they are $k$-coloured, or prove if there's a homomorphism from $A$ to $B$ and one from $B$ to $C$ there's also a homomorphism from $A$ to $C$ or use something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea.  You can do it in two steps.

1. Show that if $G_1,G_2,G_3$ are graphs and if $f_1\colon G_1\to G_2$ and $f_2\colon G_2 \to G_3$ are homomorphisms, then the composite $f_2\circ f_1\colon G_1\to G_3$ is a homomorphism.
2. Show that if $G$ is a graph and $H$ is a subgraph of $G$ then the inclusion map $H\to G$ that maps each vertex of $H$ to the same vertex in $G$ is a homomorphism.

Now take $G_1=H=G^{**}$, $G_2=G^*$, $G_3=G'$, let $f_1$ be the inclusion map $G^{**}\to G^*$ and let $f_2$ be the given homomorphism from $G^*$ to $G'$.

Answer (score 1):

If $G^{**}$ is a subgraph of $G^*$ then the canonical inclusion map is a graph homomorphism $G^{**}\to G^*$. Then we obtain a homomorphism $G^{**}\to G'$ simply by composition of homomorphisms.